# JavaScript / Jquery - Running a script on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html form that centers a select list and I am using this code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#primary_category').on('change', function(){
    var n = this.getAttribute('size'),
        i = this.selectedIndex,
        l = this.options.length;
    this.selectedIndex = Math.min(l-1,i+n/2|0);
    this.selectedIndex = Math.max(0,i+1-n/2|0);
    this.selectedIndex = i;
});
    });
</script>
```

In the above code I have `on('change` and every time I change my selection, the choice of my selection is centered. Though when I refresh the page the selection doesn't remained centered. Though the original selection remains selected.

I would like that when the page is reloaded the selection remains centered. I tried `$('#primary_category').on('load', function(){` but when I refreshed the page it didn't remain centered.

Comment: Place your code directly in `$(document).ready(function(){`

Comment: what technology are you using? maybe at the beginning you need to handle that by css

Comment: I am using HTML and PHP

Comment: What are "narrow scripts"?

Comment: @DaveNewton I updated my question subject

Answer (score 0):

Trigger change event on the `#primary_category` element on page load.
Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#primary_category').on('change', function(){
        var n = this.getAttribute('size'),
            i = this.selectedIndex,
            l = this.options.length;
        this.selectedIndex = Math.min(l-1,i+n/2|0);
        this.selectedIndex = Math.max(0,i+1-n/2|0);
        this.selectedIndex = i;
    });
    $('#primary_category').change();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: How do I go about it?

Comment: I tried it but the problem that the page keeps on reloading all the time and I can't reach to the bottom of the page.

Comment: Not sure if your issue is resolved, but why are you changing the selectedIndex 3 times. Can you explain what are you trying to achieve? Also are there any other change event handlers bound to #primary_category